# Examples: PDE with slow decay

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, examples-counterexamples

To test a numerical algorithm, I am looking for a PDE with slow decay behavior, in the following sense:

- If it is a stationary PDE on the full Euclidean space,  I am looking for one that converges to its value at infinity (not necessarily zero) at an algebraic rate
- If it is a time dependent PDE,  I am looking for one that converges to its stationary solution at an algebraic rate

Comment: if $f$ has compact support, then the solution to $-\Delta u = f$ decays as $\frac{1}{|x|^{n - 2}}$